# Why is JsonAdapter annotation ignored when serializing built-in type?

Tags: java, json, gson

#### The Problem

Imagine the following field:

```
@JsonAdapter(CustomTypeAdapter.class)
private int field;
```

When *deserializing*, the `CustomTypeAdapter`'s `read` method is called as usual, but when *serializing*, the `write` method is completely ignored and the built-in type is written out as it would ordinarily be. (The same thing happens if I use `Integer` instead of `int`.)

#### The Question

I cannot find anything in [the documentation](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/annotations/JsonAdapter.html) which says that this is the expected behavior. Is it? Or is this a bug?

#### A Workaround

The only workaround I've been able to find is to create a custom "holder" type and then expose that, e.g.,

```
@JsonAdapter(CustomTypeAdapter.class)
class CustomType { /* blah blah */ }

private CustomType field;

public int getField() {
    return field.getValue();
}

public void setField(int field) {
    this.field = new CustomType(field);
}
```

This works but is a bit more cumbersome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I agree that it should not work for `int`, I can't reproduce the behavior that it *doesn't* for `Integer` in Gson 2.3.1. First of all, you **must** use [`TypeAdapter<Integer>`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) (or a `TypeAdapterFactory`) and not `JsonSerializer`. It specifically says so in the [`JsonAdapter`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/annotations/JsonAdapter.html) Javadoc.

> The class referenced by this annotation must be either a [`TypeAdapter`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) or a [`TypeAdapterFactory`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory.html). Using the factory interface makes it possible to delegate to the enclosing `Gson` instance.

Then, the type is *not* autoboxed, so if you want to use the annotation, the field must be an `Integer`. Combining these two facts in a toy example (again, `int` won't work), we have:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.annotations.JsonAdapter;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;

public class JsonAdapterExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gson g = new Gson();

    System.out.println(g.toJson(new Car()));
  }

  public static class Car {
    @JsonAdapter(IdAdapter.class)
    Integer id = 10;
  }

  public static class IdAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer read(JsonReader arg0) throws IOException {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter arg0, Integer arg1) throws IOException {
      arg0.beginObject();
      arg0.name("id");
      arg0.value(String.valueOf(arg1));
      arg0.endObject();
    } 
  }
}
```

Output:

```
{"id":{"id":"10"}}
```

If it didn't work, it would be `10` not `"10"`, and there'd be no inner object.

Comment: I tried it with `TypeAdapter<Integer>` with no luck. I'm going to `git branch` my project and give it another try. Perhaps I was hallucinating.

Comment: @GregoryHigley Perhaps you didn't try both things at the same time?

Comment: That's entirely possible. What I may have done was kept `TypeAdapter<Integer>` but left the field as `int` instead of `Integer`. I'm pretty sure I did not, but I'll give it another whirl.

Comment: OK, I finally had time to test this. I was _certain_ I'd tested this particular scenario—hence my mention of it—but I guess I had not. In any case, thanks! My code is now much cleaner.